# python in Maya practice: Why is it returning two different nodeType answers when using the same definition?

Tags: python, maya

Maya 2020
Python 2.7
I'm still a newb at python and trying to figure out why I'm getting two different answers when finding the **nodeType** of an object.

If I execute a definition I get the correct answer.  If I execute a definition that executes the first definition I get `None`. This is incorrect. How can I get two different answers when executing the same code?

See the code below?  Select a polygon, or joint, or anything in Maya and run `pjc_object_suffix(selectedObjectName)`.  I get the correct shape node.  But running `pjc_auto_rename_selection()`, which call the previous function, somehow changes the answer to `None`.

```
def pjc_auto_rename_selection(): 
    sel=pm.selected()
    for each in sel:
        pjc_object_suffix(each)

def pjc_object_suffix(obj):      
    print ("OBJ is {}".format(obj) )
    theNodeType =mc.nodeType(obj)
    print ("OBJ nodeType is {}".format(theNodeType) )

    if theNodeType == "transform":
        shapeNodes = mc.listRelatives(obj, s=1, f=1)[0]       
        print ("shapeNodes  is {}".format(shapeNodes))
        theShapeNodeType = mc.nodeType(shapeNodes)
        print ("theShapeNodeType is {}".format(theShapeNodeType))    
        return theShapeNodeType
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem is that you mix pymel and maya commands. Pymel work with objects, maya commands work with strings so if you do:

```
sel=pm.selected()
```

you get a list of objects, whereas if you call the `pjc_object_suffix()` directly with a string you have a string. If you are using pymel, you could do it in a more decent way like this:

```
def pjc_auto_rename_selection(): 
    sel=pm.selected()
    for each in sel:
        pjc_object_suffix(each)

def pjc_object_suffix(obj):        
    shapeNode = obj  
    if obj.type() == "transform":
        shapeNode = obj.getShape()
        ...
```

Comment: doh!  I'm doing a tutorial that's mixing languages and I didn't realize it.  Thank you for clarifying.  I'll stick with one language at a time for  while.